# Getting an Animated node with ID 2 already exists error on opening the downloaded apk from expo, react-native-reanimated version is ~2.12.0,

Tags: react-native

[Animated node with ID 2 already exists error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4K0h.png)

"expo": "47.0.12", "react-native": "0.70.5",   "react-native-reanimated": "~2.12.0" these are my versions using in project, I facing the above error when I'm trying to open the app ?